# Rails 5 upgrade unwanted redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am upgrading an app from Rails 4 to Rails 5. I am getting unknown redirect 301 on some of my routes. Here is how it looks like.

The Route file

```
  namespace :api, :path => '/api' do
    namespace :v1 do
      scope module: 'users' do
        post 'users/login', to: 'login#post'
      end
    end
  end
```

The Controllers:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class Users::LoginController < ApiController
    end
  end
end
```

The parent controller

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ApiController < ActionController::Base
    end
  end
end
```

Inside the controllers I had some code, but as I was debugging I removed all the code and the problem was still there, so I infer that the issue is not in the code in the controllers.

The test case

```
it "does not authenticate if the Authorization header is not present" do

  post '/api/v1/users/login'

  expect(json["message"]).to eq("This endpoint requires Authorization in the header")
  expect(response.status).to eq 401
end
```

Instead of anything like this I get the following error.

```
Failures:

  1) Users API POST /users/login does not authenticate if the Authorization header is not present
     Failure/Error: JSON.parse(response.body)

     JSON::ParserError:
       784: unexpected token at '<html><body>You are being <a href="http://www.example.com/api/v1/users/login.json">redirected</a>.</body></html>'
     # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
     # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
     # ./spec/support/request_helpers.rb:4:in `json'
     # ./spec/requests/api/v1/users/login_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

> Edit

When I fire up my server and use Postman to make the calls, I see the request being changes from `POST` to `GET`. For some endpoints it fires the `GET` call multiple times.

```
Started POST "/api/v1/users/login" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-11-24 08:49:45 +0000
Started GET "/api/v1/users/login.json" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-11-24 08:49:46 +0000
```

> Edit
>   Adding Route

```
api_v1_users_login POST   /api/v1/users/login(.:format)                         api/v1/users/login#post
```

I am not sure how to go about debugging this. Any idea on what could be wrong here?

Comment: paste the output of rake routes

Comment: Do you want all the routes? As there are many of them.

Comment: I need the route of login

Comment: added the rake route

Comment: How do your controllers authenticate the request? More specifically: is your authentication code redirecting the request?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have post action in your `Users::LoginController`. 
Create a `post method` in above, then it will work.

Comment: As I said, I had the methods there and it showed the same error. If I understand it right, when a method is missing we will get `action` not define error and not a redirect.

Comment: When a method is not present, it will give 404 error

Comment: might be you have some similar route , paste the complete output of rake routes

Comment: You were right. :)
There was a route before the main route which was hijacking it. It was working on the previous version, so never gave a thought.